# How to update global variable in infinite loop using multiprocess

Tags: python, textbox, global, multiprocess

I have the following simple code. There is one button and entry widget.

When I clicked button, changeText read entry_widget value and assign to 'var'. mainWindow and InfiniteLoop are running same time. But in InfiniteLoop variable var's value doesn't change. How to change its value?

```
import tkinter as Tk
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process
import time
var = 'Unchanged'

root = Tk.Tk()
root.geometry('740x306')
root.title("Performance")

id_label = Tk.Label(master=root, text="Id: ")
id_label.pack()

entry_widget = Tk.Entry(master=root, font=30)
entry_widget.pack()

def changeText():
  global var
  var = entry_widget.get() #var is changed here. example var's value is: a
  print_var() # var = a and printing a. 
def print_var():
  print(var) # var's value is a and its working here.

def aaa():
  id_label.config(font=30)
  id_label.place(x=10, y=5)
  entry_widget.place(x=33, y=5)


  sumbit_button = Tk.Button(master=root, text='Sumbit', command=changeText)
  sumbit_button.pack()
  sumbit_button.place(x=250, y=2)
  Tk.mainloop()

def forLoop():
  while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print_var() #doesn't work here. print Unchanged

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=aaa)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=forLoop)
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call changeText method to update value. If you want to do this inside InfiniteLoop;

```
#Button's command
  def changeText():
    global var
    var = entry_widget.get()
    return var
```

---

```
def InfiniteLoop():
  var = changeText()
  while True:
    print(var)
```

Comment: Please provide more information instead not working... I have debugged your code's simplified version. Please see for refer;

var = "UnChanged"
def changeText():

    var = "Changed..."
    return var

def InfiniteLoop():
    while True:
        text = changeText()
        print(text)

InfiniteLoop()

Comment: I updated the code. please control it. Only in for loop doesn't work. out of for everything is good.